# sequence of ordered numbers in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate sequence of ordered numbers which is of same length of some other list. I have tried

```
def parse_data_from_file(filename):
    times = []
    temperatures = []

    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(reader)
        
        for row in reader:
            times.append(row[0])
            temperatures.append(float(row[1]))
            
    return times, temperatures
```

The issue is time is not getting represnted properly on x-axis as attached here:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what this has to do with a sequence of ordered numbers. Are you asking for `range(len(some_list))`?

Comment: I have to strip date colum completely which i did as per your mention, but time shoud be of same length as of temperature list. temperature list is accesses by row[1]. sorry for the late reply as time difference

Comment: after appending timelist now x-axis is reprented with year itself i need to replace it with simple list starting from 0 which is of same length i.e of temperatures

Comment: i just have to reverse the sequence of operation i mean first i generated temperature list then just taken the length of temperature list for generating time list. Its done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you're making the plots. I'll assume you're using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html), which is probably the most popular plotting package for Python.

I know that when I'm working with dates or times, I usually use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to get the data into a datetime format that Python likes:

```
from datetime import datetime

# assume your date info looks like 08-Jun-2022 14:22:22
dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
times.append(dt)
```

Matplotlib has a convenience function `date2num` that converts a datetime object to a format that it likes to use. Their official example is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html). Here is an even shorter example for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = matplotlib.dates.date2num(times)
y = temperatures
ax.plot(t, y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=(1, 7)))
```